# How to shows featured products in product page by category in magento?

Tags: magento

I need to show featured products in product page by category, I created attribute to set featured product in admin panel, It working fine in admin panel,I need to get all the featured products by corresponding category in products page.
I am novice to magento , so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find detailed tutorial from [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/how_to_create_a_featured_product) to create featured product.